# Import SQL Server 2008 db in Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using `SQL server 2008`, Want to import my db to `Azure`. I have (*.bak) file. Is their any work around to restore my db to `Azure` without changing my db structure.

I tried `SQLAzureMW` but it is giving me this error

> 'Filegroup reference and partitioning scheme' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I searched `Filegroup` keyword in scripts but it isn't there.

I also tried `Azure SilverLight Managment Tool` but it giving me same error.

While running this `script` i am getting the above error.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [Mohsin].[Supplier](
    [SuppID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [street] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](17) NULL,
    [Fax] [varchar](17) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Supplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SuppID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there isn't a reference for an Index or object indicating that it should go on the Primary filegroup.  Search for `ON [PRIMARY]` or `ON PRIMARY`, or just the word `PRIMARY`.

The SQL Azure Migration Wizard is usually pretty good about pointing out exactly what it doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks. plz see my updated question. what changes i have to make to run it.

Comment: Remove the ON [PRIMARY].  I see it in there twice. That's an instruction to place the index on the primary filegroup.